# How we can guarantee synchronous behaviour in Javascript when we need it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise, synchronous

I am new to Javascript programming and this is a somewhat contrived example, but it is at the heart of a number of problems I have where I need to synchronously sequence some processing in javascript.

Say I have two text files
Sample1.text which contains

```
line number 1
line number 2
line number 3
line number 4
line number 5
line number 6
line number 7
```

And Sample2.txt which contains

```
line number 8
line number 9
line number 10
line number 11
line number 12
line number 13
line number 14
```

I need to process them so that Sample1.txt always completes processing before Sample2.txt

Here is my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { mainModule } = require("process");
// const readline = require("readline");

const readline = require("readline-promise").default;

const rlp2 = readline.createInterface({
  terminal: false,
  input: fs.createReadStream("sample2.txt"),
});

const rlp1 = readline.createInterface({
  terminal: false,
  input: fs.createReadStream("sample1.txt"),
});

// No top-level await in JS yet, so we put it in an async function
async function processLineByLine_1_7() {
  for await (const line of rlp2) console.log(`Read this line: ${line}`);
}

// No top-level await in JS yet, so we put it in an async function
async function processLineByLine_8_14() {
  for await (const line of rlp1) {
    console.log(`Read this line: ${line}`);
  }
}

processLineByLine_1_7();
processLineByLine_8_14();
```

---

And the output:

```
Read this line: line number 8
Read this line: line number 9
Read this line: line number 10
Read this line: line number 11
Read this line: line number 12
Read this line: line number 13
Read this line: line number 1
Read this line: line number 2
Read this line: line number 3
Read this line: line number 4
Read this line: line number 5
Read this line: line number 6
Read this line: line number 7
Read this line: line number 14
```

How do I guarantee the order? So that I always guarantee the order so that I always get:

```
Read this line: line number 1
Read this line: line number 2
Read this line: line number 3
Read this line: line number 4
Read this line: line number 5
Read this line: line number 6
Read this line: line number 7
Read this line: line number 8
Read this line: line number 9
Read this line: line number 10
Read this line: line number 11
Read this line: line number 12
Read this line: line number 13
Read this line: line number 14
```

I trying to understand how we can **guarantee synchronous behaviour** when we need it.
Is it possible to wrap the functions processLineByLine_1_7 in a promise with for await constructs or is there some other way?

If I try this:

```
async function main() {

  await processLineByLine_1_7();
  await processLineByLine_8_14();
}
```

main();

I see the following output:

```
> node .

Read this line: line number 8
Read this line: line number 9
Read this line: line number 10
Read this line: line number 11
Read this line: line number 12
Read this line: line number 13
Read this line: line number 14
```

Comment: `await processLineByLine_1_7();await processLineByLine_8_14();` ???

Comment: Thanks Keith, but await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules. Also I believe that processLineByLine_1_7() would need to return a promise.

Comment: Yes, so you put it inside an `async` function and run that.. `processLineByLine_1_7() `  IS returning a Promise.

Comment: async function main() {
  //if (isPromise(processLineByLine_1_7)) console.log("Returns a promise");
  await processLineByLine_1_7();
  await processLineByLine_8_14();
}

main();
output
> node .
`
Read this line: line number 8
Read this line: line number 9
Read this line: line number 10
Read this line: line number 11
Read this line: line number 12
Read this line: line number 13
Read this line: line number 14
`

Comment: Note that you use `rlp2` in `1_7` and `rlp1` in `8_14`. I guess that's a typo?!

Comment: Yes, I saw and fixed that after posting, thanks Yoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your *readline interfaces* already start processing, as such the order is mixed up. Try only creating them when actually needed, e.g.:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline-promise").default;

async function processLineByLine_1_7() {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream("sample1.txt"),
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    console.log(`Read this line: ${line}`);
  }
}

async function processLineByLine_8_14() {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream("sample2.txt"),
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    console.log(`Read this line: ${line}`);
  }
}

(async () => {
  await processLineByLine_1_7();
  await processLineByLine_8_14();
})();
```

Note: Obviously this could be refactored to be *"more dry"*.

Comment: Thanks Yoshi, yes the problem was the interfaces. I moved them inside the functions and that resolved the issue. So I guess the initial confusions was whether I could await on the processLineByLine function as Keith and Prime pointed out.

Comment: Strange!!,  placing the createInterface into the functions,  if this is indeed part of the solution.  It would imply that an `async generator` is consuming into some empty void.. Weird!!...

Comment: @Keith I was surprised as well and wouldn't have assumed such a behavior. My guess is, that creating the interface outside anything that's *waiting* for it, let's it do what promises do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach `await` in front of `processLineByLine_1_7` & `processLineByLine_8_14`.

```
await processLineByLine_1_7();
await processLineByLine_8_14();
```